# How can I show a summary in the footer of a win grid and not have the Sigma show up in the header?

Tags: sum, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I'm using an Infragistics UltraWinGrid and would like to be able to display the sum of several columns. I got that working by allowing row summaries. However, I only want them to be able to see the sum, not have all these other crazy options that come along with that little sigma in the header. How can I get rid of this while keeping the sums at the bottom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have the DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowSummaries property set in this way:

```
DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowSummaries = AllowRowSummaries.Default;
```

then use code like this to create your summary
(Need to check before creating another summary with the same name)

```
private void BuildCurrencySummary(string name, UltraGridColumn col)
{
    SummarySettings ss = grd.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Summaries.Add(name, SummaryType.Sum, col);
    ss.SummaryPositionColumn = col;
    ss.SummaryPosition = SummaryPosition.UseSummaryPositionColumn;
    ss.Appearance.FontData.Bold = Infragistics.Win.DefaultableBoolean.True;
    ss.Appearance.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    ss.Appearance.TextHAlign = HAlign.Right;
    ss.DisplayFormat = "{0:C}";
}
```

Comment: The UltraGridColumn also exposes an AllowRowSummaries property so that you can enable or disable the sigma icon on an individual column.

Comment: @alhalama, thanks never paid attention to this. Oh well sometimes the amount of properties in that grid are overwhelming

Comment: Perfect! Just because I was a little confused by your wording, myself, I would like to make clear for future readers: It should be DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowSummaries = AllowRowSummaries.Default;

Answer (score 0):

From [Infragistics Forum](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/25250.aspx) :

You can still apply summaries to a column without setting the AllowRowSummaries property.

The purpose of the AllowRowSummaries is to show (or not show) the interface for the user to establish their own summaries.  This is the "sigma" symbol you were seeing.

From the Override object, set the AllowRowSummaries property to False.

```
UltraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.AllowRowSummaries = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.AllowRowSummaries.[False]
```